# How to define a global-set-key for M-x color-theme-<TAB> RET

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I haven't been able to locate any examples of how to use global-set-key in conjunction with `M-x color-theme-<TAB> RET`.  I've tried several variations, but to no avail.  Is it possible to insert a tab at the end of color-theme?

```
(global-set-key "\C-ct" 'color-theme<TAB><RET>)
```

Comment: TAB does completion, so what does color-theme<TAB> complete to?  Just use that, possibly wrapped in a (lambda () (interactive) (color-theme-whatever)).

Comment: Essentially what happens is that pressing the tab and return key puts a hyphen at the end of `color-theme-` and brings up a window displaying the names of all 75 themes to choose from, and then the user can type in the remainder of theme title and then press return again.  `color-theme-black-on-grey`.

Comment: You could probably create a named macro for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This keyboard shortcut pulls up a similar screen that can be clicked with a mouse.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'color-theme-select)
```

---

On a related note:

Aquamacs 2.4 disables the color-theme menubar entry under tools.  So if anyone wants to enable it, then insert this into the Preferences.el or init.el (if you have one):

```
(easy-menu-add-item nil color-theme-entry-path "--")
(easy-menu-add-item  nil color-theme-entry-path
           ["Color Themes" color-theme-select t])
```

Aquamacs 2.4 already has this somewhere else in its initialization:

```
(require 'easymenu)
```

Alternatively, the user can remove the `;;` from `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/color-theme.el` at lines 513 to 516.